# Best way to handle progress HUD in multiple parallel async request in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am making multiple parallel async request to REST api in swift , I am using MBProgressHUD to display the spinner currently I am using variables to control multiple request but want to know best design pattern to handle spinner in multiple async requests

Answer (score 0):

Keep a count of the APIs. In their respective completion block, decrement this count by 1. In every completion block check for the count. Remove the spinner when the count reaches 0.

**Edit 1**: You can use `dispatch_group_async` and `dispatch_group_notify`. Create group of requests with `dispatch_group_async` and `dispatch_group_notify` will notify you once all the requests are complete. Use this to hide your spinner/activity indicator.

**Edit 2**: Thanks @brandonscript for pointing this out.
 Dispatch group can be used as:

```
let dispatchGroup = dispatch_group_create()
    let dispatchQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.test.proj", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT)

    dispatch_group_async(dispatchGroup, dispatchQueue, {
         print("In thread 1")
    })

    dispatch_group_async(dispatchGroup, dispatchQueue, {
        print("In thread 2")
    })

    dispatch_group_notify(dispatchGroup, dispatchQueue, {
        print("Dispatch group execution complete")
    })
```

**Console Output**: In thread 1

In thread 2

Dispatch notify complete

Comment: `dispatch_group` is definitely a more appropriate solution than manually maintaining a counter, but you should also need to explain how to use them, otherwise your answer reads more like a comment than an answer.